# Do the front buttons on the Droid X turn on the screen?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, screen

I had an LG Optimus V phone and the physical buttons on the front could get pressed when it was in my pocket, which would turn on the screen.

I'm considering a phone (Droid X) with physical buttons b/c I *like* the physical buttons easier to see and feel when using).  But.... I don't want the screen turning on all the time (and draining the battery).

Does the Droid X's  row of menu/back/search buttons turn the screen on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Home button (and possibly the Volume buttons) turn on the screen.

Found a fix on: http://www.droidforums.net/forum/drod2169-x/132091-ocd-stop-home-button-waking-screen-save-battery.html

Have not tested yet, but it's mentioned in several places. Not sure if it works on an unrooted phone.

GINGERBREAD

---

Open /system/usr/keylayout/sholes-keypad.kl
remove "Wake_Dropped" And/or "Wake" after any entries for:
HOME
MENU
SEARCH
BACK
VOLUME UP
VOLUME DOWN

---

FROYO

---

Open /system/usr/keylayout/cdma_shadow-keypad.kl
remove "Wake_Dropped" And/or "Wake" after any entries for:
HOME
MENU
SEARCH
BACK
VOLUME UP
VOLUME DOWN

---